# Load Startup File

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell, path

my linux terminal keeps giving me the error: java command not found. I found these instructions online and am trying to follow them step by step:

Bash Shell

1. Edit the startup file (~/.bashrc)
2. Modify PATH variable

   ```
   PATH=/usr/local/jdk1.8.0/bin:$PATH 
   export PATH
   ```
3. Save and close the file
4. Load the startup file

   ```
   % . /.profile
   ```
5. Verify that the path is set by repeating the java command

   ```
   % java -version
   ```

**What I've done:** 
I've edited the .bashrc file

**Problem**

I can't seem to  Load the startup file using the . /.profile command.
This is what shows up if I try:

```
➤ . /.profile
bash: /.profile: No such file or directory
```

I also tried directly checking if it fixed the issue but it did not:

```
 ➤ java -version
bash: java: command not found
```

Comment: are you connecting to a server with mobaxterm or just opening it's terminal.i don't think that you can treat moba's terminal as a full linux distro. if this is the case, install a VM manager and create a linux vm that you can connect to with moba

Comment: yes im using mobaxterm

Comment: would git bash work?

Comment: `% . /.profile` the slash `/` attempts to load a `.profile` from the root directory.  Omit the slash as in `. .profile` or `. ~/.profile`

Comment: both of those just allow for linux like things to happen. or to use the utilities that come packaged with them on your local machine. You may be able to do this with Bash for windows. this is a hacky way to get a linux vm but i've had issues with it persisting settings between uses. See VirtualBox or HyperVmanager download a linux ISO and do it for real.

Answer (score 0):

Debian comes with a default `~/.profile` that sources `~/.bashrc`. The writer did not realize that this is not a universal thing. Additionally you dropped the leading `.` and space.

Instead, just source `.bashrc` directly:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: I tried that but it didn't help with th eproblem of java

Comment: it still says java: command not found when I type java -version

Comment: Also, sorry about the attempted command. I have edited it to reflect the proper results.

Comment: What does `echo "$PATH"` say?

Comment: /bin:/usr/bin:/drives/c/windows:/drives/c/windows/system32

Comment: Can you post your `~/.bashrc`?

Comment: PATH=/usr/local/jdk1.8.0/bin:$PATH
export PATH

Comment: 1. Is that one or two lines? 2. Are you sure these are the only two lines in the entire file? 3. Can you confirm that this is the content shown when you do `cat ~/.bashrc`? 4. Can you double check that `source ~/.bashrc` *immediately* followed by `echo "$PATH"` *in the same terminal* still does not show `jdk1.8.0`? 5. Can you copy-paste an unabbreviated input and output from your terminal for steps 2, 3 and 4?

Comment: 1. that is 2 lines. 






2. Yes, I'm sure. 
3.  `code`➤ cat ~/.bashrc |more
PATH=/usr/local/jdk1.8.0/bin:$PATH
export PATH`code`

Comment: 4. Yes, confirmed

`code`
[2018-08-31 17:57.55]  /home
[kb60500.H18NBFI12PS0033] ➤  source ~/.bashrc
                                                                                                                                    ✔
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
[2018-08-31 17:59.21]  /home
[kb60500.H18NBFI12PS0033] ➤ echo "$PATH"
/usr/local/jdk1.8.0/bin:/usr/local/jdk1.8.0/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/drives/c/windows:/drives/c/windows/system32

`code`

Comment: @MarkJ As you can see, the `/usr/local/jdk1.8.0/bin` has been correctly added to your PATH (twice, even). If you are getting `java: command not found`, it's because you don't have java installed in that directory on that system. Note that you can not follow Linux instructions if you are running Windows, no matter what kind of terminal you use on Windows.

Comment: what can i do to fix this?

Comment: should i reinstall java?

Comment: Also, java works on my cmd. It's just on my linux terminal that I'm havign this issue

Comment: There's no such thing as a Linux terminal for Windows, there's only emulation, simulation, ports and remoting. What are you actually running? WSL? If so, find documentation for how to install Java on WSL.

Comment: I'm using git bash

Answer (score 0):

both of those just allow for linux like things to happen. or to use the utilities that come packaged with them on your local machine. You may be able to do this with Bash for windows. this is a hacky way to get a linux vm but i've had issues with it persisting settings between uses. See VirtualBox or HyperVmanager download a linux ISO and do it for real.